# How to use graphene dataloader on connections and how to select only necessary fields

Tags: python, graphene-python

I would like to use some non-standard database with python graphene to create a GraphQL endpoint. This database doesn't have existing SQLAlchemy dialect, is not supported by Django ORM etc., so I'm trying to use `DataLoader` class to extract data with batches and minimize the number of queries to database.
I read the https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/execution/dataloader/. To illustrate my problems I created the next simplified ready-to-use example:

```
import graphene

from graphql.execution.executors.asyncio import AsyncioExecutor
from starlette.applications import Starlette

from starlette.routing import Route
from starlette.graphql import GraphQLApp

from graphene.relay import Node, Connection, ConnectionField
from graphene import String, ObjectType, Field, List, NonNull

from promise import Promise
from promise.dataloader import DataLoader



class User(ObjectType):
    """User information."""

    class Meta:
        interfaces = (Node,)

    user_id = String(description='User id.', name='userID')
    user_name = String(description='User name.')

    @classmethod
    def get_node(cls, info, _id):
        return user_loader.load(_id)


class UserConnection(Connection):
    class Meta:
        node = User


def get_user(_id):
    return User(id=_id,
                user_id=_id,
                user_name='Bill Gates',
                )


user_data = {x.id: x for x in [get_user(f'EEE-{x}') for x in range(8)]}


class UserLoader(DataLoader):

    def batch_load_fn(self, keys):
        return Promise.resolve([user_data.get(key) for key in keys])


user_loader = UserLoader()


class Query(ObjectType):
    user = Field(User,
                user_id=String(description='User ID', name='userID', required=True),
                description='User Information')
    users = List(User,
                     user_ids=List(NonNull(String), name='userIDs', required=True),
                     required=True)
    all_users = ConnectionField(UserConnection)

    node = Node.Field()


    def resolve_user(self, info, user_id):
        return user_loader.load(user_id)

    def resolve_users(self, info, user_ids):
        return user_loader.load_many(user_ids)

    def resolve_all_users(self, info, **args):
        return list(user_data.values())


routes = [
    Route('/',
          GraphQLApp(schema=graphene.Schema(query=Query),
                     executor_class=AsyncioExecutor)
          ),
]


app = Starlette(routes=routes)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8000)
```

I expect the following GraphQL queries to be working:

```
fragment userFields on User {
  userID
  userName
}


query getUser {
  user(userID: "EEE-3") {
    id
    ...userFields
  }
}


query getUsers {
  users(userIDs: ["EEE-3", "EEE-4", "EEE-5"]) {
    id
    ...userFields
  }
}


query getNode {
  node(id: "VXNlcjpFRUUtMw==") {
    id
    ... on User {
      ...userFields
    }
  }
}

query getAllUsers {
  allUsers(first: 2) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        ...userFields
      }
      cursor
    }
    pageInfo{
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
      startCursor
      endCursor
    }
  }
}
```

Here I don't use that database to keep the example simple, because my questions are about how to use the `DataLoader` correctly, or what else should I do to reach my purposes. I have the data in the `user_data` variable and access them using `get_user` function, but in real situation it would be a query to my database.

Here everything seems working well except two things:

1. The function `resolve_all_users` works directly on the underlying dataset, or full query. While I want it to serve as some pagination interface that extracts only necessary data depending on arguments like `first`, `after` and so on. I can explicitly call `resolve_connection` function on `UserConnection` class and I see it uses some array slicing functions. But `Dataloader` in the example uses `User` ids and not indices. Also it seems expensive to create index `Dataloader` as I want to get continuous interval and don't want to pass all indices as list. What should I do here to resolve this field using only one request?
2. Also with `DataLoader` I extract from the database the complete `User` objects even if not all fields have been required. Is it possible to optimize this to extract only required in the GraphQL query fields?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I feel like your question is more related to this: [Document how to implement Connection fields and pagination](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/887). 

Maybe you can get inspiration from graphene-sqlalchemy [implementation](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-sqlalchemy/blob/master/graphene_sqlalchemy/fields.py).

I think reading this function [connection_from_array_slice](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphql-relay-py/blob/514402e98ec3aee1949469e8133d0268d06975cf/src/graphql_relay/connection/arrayconnection.py#L101) might help

Comment: As far as the dataloader part is concerned, I think you can rewrite `resolve_all_users` to first 1) get the keys, 2) resolve them using the loader. Except from that I really think the problem is somewhat unrelated to dataloader. 


`keys = list(user_data.keys())[: args["first"]]`, then `return user_loader.load_many(keys)` but obviously the hard part here is how to get the keys without requesting all keys from your data store (I guess).